# Freemarker шаблонизатор в war файле

Tags: java, java-ee, шаблонизаторы, freemarker

Нужно сделать так чтобы в war файле был класс который обрабатывал статичные страницы шаблонов, как указать шаблонизатору правильный путь к папке с шаблонами, пробовал несколько разных способов как в мануале.

Как правильно прописать в конструкторе инициализацию папки с шаблонами?

```
private static PageGeneration pageGenerator;
private final Configuration cfg;

public static PageGeneration instance() {
    if (pageGenerator == null)
        pageGenerator = new PageGeneration();
    return pageGenerator;
}

public String getPage(String filename, Map<String, Object> data) {
    Writer stream = new StringWriter();
    try {
        Template template = cfg.getTemplate(filename);
        template.process(data, stream);

    } catch (IOException  | TemplateException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return stream.toString();
}

private PageGeneration() {

        cfg = new Configuration();

        cfg.setClassForTemplateLoading(this.getClass(), "/WEB-INF/templates");
```

}
}

В логе томкэта исключение

freemarker.template.TemplateNotFoundException: Template not found for name "user
_identefication.html".
The name was interpreted by this TemplateLoader: ClassTemplateLoader(resourceLoa
derClass=pagegenerator.PageGeneration, basePackagePath="/WEB-INF/templates/").

Comment: С этими загрузчиками вообще мутная тема. Загрузчик this.Class-а скорей всего и не видит WEB-INF. Попробуйте указать такой `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();` Но это вряд ли поможет. Мне не помогло. Если есть возможность сделать свой загрузчик, то сделать его, используя ServletContext : `getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/templates/user _identefication.html");` Последний приём использовал для загрузки шаблонов Apache Velocity. Самое трудное - сообразить как получить ServletContext где-нибудь, кроме сервлета.

Comment: Мне стрим не нужен, мне нужно чтобы он увидел путь, который нужно указать как в мануале на странице фримейкера. который кстати тоже не хочет работать

Comment: Вместо `cfg.setClassForTemplateLoading(Class resourceLoaderClass, String basePackagePath)` Вам надо использовать `cfg.setServletContextForTemplateLoading(Object servletContext, String path)`. `servletContext` получить из `request`.

Comment: Заработало, только как мне теперь передавать сервлет контекст правильно в мой класс, пока напилил так:   ' private TemplateWorker(ServletContext context) {
            cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.setServletContextForTemplateLoading(context,"WEB-INF/templates");
            cfg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
            cfg.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.HTML_DEBUG_HANDLER); '

Answer (score 0):

Для начала Вам не следует делать инициализацию в конструкторе, отделите ее в метод инициализации:

```
public class PageGeneration {
    private static PageGeneration pageGenerator;
    private final Configuration cfg;

    public static PageGeneration instance() {
        if (pageGenerator == null)
            pageGenerator = new PageGeneration();
        return pageGenerator;
    }

    public String getPage(String filename, Map<String, Object> data) {
         ...
    }

    private PageGeneration() {
        cfg = new Configuration();
    }

    public void init(String templatesDirectoryPath) {
        configuration.setTemplateLoader(new FileTemplateLoader(new File(templatesDirectoryPath)));
    }   
}
```

Чтобы выполнить инициализацию конфигурации Freemarker внутри Tomcat потребуется использовать ServletContext для разрешения пути.

Операции с контекстом уместно обработать внутри слушателя:

```
@WebListener
public class ContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        try {
            ServletContext context = sce.getServletContext();
            initTemplater(context);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    }


    private void initTemplater(ServletContext context) throws IOException {
        String templatesPath = context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/templates");
        PageGeneration.instance().init(templatesPath);
    }
}
```